# In a NodeJs microservices Architecture, should I use a package.json per service?

Tags: node.js, microservices

I'm currently developing a microservices architecture in NodeJs. My first approach, was a `package.json` per service. Although, it can be very tricky when accessing to a common area (with logging or database utils), for all microservices. For instance:

```
common-area >
    logger.js
    package.json - install module typeorm

service1 >
    app.js - use logger.js
    package.json - also install module typeorm
```

When running `node app.js` (Service 1) we end up with 2 typeorm modules loaded, once we made two different installations, one in common area (used by logger) and another in service1.

Should I use only one `package.json`, for all micro-services, resulting in only one `node_modules` folder?

Comment: I'm not if you are using micro-services here. Each service should be isolated, and typically communicate via a queue (RabbitMQ, Kafka) or remove request (HTTP, RPC). This looks like you are loading the `logger` "service" inside `service1` - which goes against this practice. I think your `logger.js` is a module reused in other services, not a service. Maybe publish it as a private node package? - I may be completely misunderstanding, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are right. `Logger.js` is not a service, just a common module, used by all services. Publishing as private node package seems to be a good idea :) Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I use only one package.json, for all micro-services, resulting >in only one node_modules folder?

You shouldn't worry about having multiple node_modules directories when you're doing microservices because one of the points of microservices is to be able to put them on separate hosts or in separate containers and they won't be able to share their dependencies anyway.

Every microservice should be a separate service. You should avoid tight coupling and possible leaky abstractions that can result from fighting against the microservice architecture and joining them together.

Of course microservices is not the only architecture that works in practice but you want microservices then every microservice should be completely independent. Otherwise it's not microservices.

If there is any common code that you can share among the services then put it in a module that would be required by all or some of the services as needed. You can keep private modules on npm, you can host a private npm registry, or you can install that module directly from GitHub or GitLab private repos. All you need to do to add a private (or public) module hosted on GitHub would be to run:

```
npm install user/repo --save
```

where `user` is your user (or organization) name on GitHub and `repo` is the name of the repository. Keep in mind that to install such a module if it's in a private repo the ssh key used on that machine would have to belong to a user that has read access to the repo. You can also use deploy keys on GitHub for more flexibility.

You can even simplify loading external dependencies in your services by creating a separate module that includes all of the dependencies and exposes them to your services all at once. E.g. if you create a module called `dependencies` that looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  _: require('lodash'),
  P: require('bluebird'),
  fs: require('mz/fs'),
  // ...
};
```

Then you can use all of those modules in your microservices like this:

```
const { _, P, fs } = require('dependencies');
```

When you have a large number of small microservices, especially when those are split into multiple files, this can simplify things quite a bit.

Comment: Yeah. That was my first approach, trying to achieve loosely coupled among services. Although, following the DRY principle, i join shared code in common area. As @Caffeinated.tech suggested, I will try to make a private module with it.

Comment: @VBoss Yes, of course you can make private modules to factor out any common code. You can have private and scoped modules on npm, you can install directly from GitHub or GitLab or any other git repo. See my updated answer.

Comment: if the external dependencies have more than 20+, how do we deal with it? do we still include it in require('dependencies')? Will it cause the deployment size to be very big?

if my project has over 30 microservices with over 20 private package. what is the better design approach? Should i change the 20 private package to single private package?

Comment: @rsp I have create a question on private packages on another article. Will be glad if you have any good suggestion.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64201915/how-do-we-design-the-multiple-npm-private-package-in-nodejs-microservices